# Streaming large file uploads to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, upload, streaming

For an application I'm working on, I need to allow the user to upload very large files--i.e., potentially many gigabytes--via our website.  Unfortunately, ASP.NET MVC appears to load the entire request into RAM before beginning to service it--not exactly ideal for such an application.  Notably, trying to circumvent the issue via code such as the following:

```
if (request.Method == "POST")
{
    request.ContentLength = clientRequest.InputStream.Length;
    var rgbBody = new byte[32768];

    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        int cbRead;
        while ((cbRead = clientRequest.InputStream.Read(rgbBody, 0, rgbBody.Length)) > 0)
        {
            fileStream.Write(rgbBody, 0, cbRead);
        }
    }
}
```

fails to circumvent the buffer-the-request-into-RAM mentality.  Is there an easy way to work around this behavior?

Comment: Where does your code reside in your application? Controller? handler? module?

Comment: I know this question is old, but it's a really good question that I'm using as a reference for a project I'm working on. Quick question -- what is the "cb" supposed to denote in your variable cbRead?

Comment: @KSwift87 `cb` stands for "Count of Bytes", which is standard Apps Hungarian notation at Fog Creek.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It turns out that my initial code was basically correct; the only change required was to change

```
request.ContentLength = clientRequest.InputStream.Length;
```

to

```
request.ContentLength = clientRequest.ContentLength;
```

The former streams in the entire request to determine the content length; the latter merely checks the `Content-Length` header, which only requires that the headers have been sent in full.  This allows IIS to begin streaming the request almost immediately, which completely eliminates the original problem.

Comment: So, basically simply touching the InputStream property defeats your disk buffering. Is it possible to obtain a stream handle to the disk-buffered file?

Comment: Not that I've been able to determine, but I stopped seriously investigating this once I got something that worked.

Answer (score 17):

Sure, you can do this. See [RESTful file uploads with HttpWebRequest and IHttpHandler](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/02/restful-file-uploads-with.html). I have been using this method for a few years and have a site that has been tested with files of at least several gigabytes. Essentially, you want to create your own IHttpHandler, which is easier than it sounds.

In a nutshell, you create a class that implements the IHttpHandler
interface, meaning you have to support the IsReusable property and the ProcessRequest method. On top of that, there is a minor change to your web.config, and it works like a charm. At this stage in the life cycle of the request, the entire file being uploaded does not get loaded into memory, so it neatly steps around out of memory issues.

Note that in the web.config,

```
<httpHandlers>
 <add verb="*" path="DocumentUploadService.upl" validate="false" type="TestUploadService.FileUploadHandler, TestUploadService"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

the file referenced, DocumentUploadService.upl, doesn't actually exist. That is just there to give an alternate extension so that the request is not intercepted by the standard handler. You point your file upload form to that path, but then your FileUploadHandler class kicks in and actually receives the file.

**Update:** Actually, the code I use is different from that article, and I think I stumbled on the reason it works. I use the [HttpPostedFile](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx) class, in which *"Files are uploaded in MIME multipart/form-data format. By default, all requests, including form fields and uploaded files, larger than 256 KB are buffered to disk, rather than held in server memory."*

```
if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    string tempFile = context.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
    for(int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile uploadFile = context.Request.Files[i];
        if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            uploadFile.SaveAs(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
              tempFile,"Upload\\", uploadFile.FileName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks nearly identical to mine; the only difference is that I'm running it in ASP.NET MVC, and you're running it directly in a new IHttpHandler.  Do you happen to know why there's a difference?  Is there something in my code that's forcing the stream to be pulled in?

Comment: How are you displaying upload progress?

Comment: I uses a Flash file uploader, this is the best way to queue multiple files for upload and get upload status. (E.g., http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlashUpload.aspx)

Comment: The IHttpHandler approach was really useful. I've integrated a similar solution in my file uploader. I needed to use GetBufferlessInputStream() to prevent ASP.NET from waiting until the post data had been fully uploaded. Some extended request processing logic is included here http://blog.appsoftware.com/post/2013/03/08/ASPNET-File-Uploader-with-SignalR-Progress-Bar-and-Extended-HTTP-Request-Processing