# File upload streaming in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Streaming large file uploads to ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046230/streaming-large-file-uploads-to-asp-net-mvc)

To my understanding, when a user upload a file to an asp.net (webforms or mvc), IIS buffers the file content to the memory and doesn't hit the application until all file content is received.
This isn't an issue for small files but for large files this is problem for obvious reasons.

In WCF there is  `transferMode="Streamed"` binding configuration to allow the WCF service to receive the request as chunks.
Is there a configuration in IIS or asp.net that allows http streaming ?

I'm using IIS 7 and asp.net mvc.

Comment: The provided answer is not correct, for me at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in asp.net model file is always a file object, not stream.
the only solution is to intercept upload at http level and handle it using non-webforms way. see "a real solution" on second page here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx