# HTTP file upload, posting to a webservice

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have a solution where the user uploads large files 4Mb - 200Mb. Right now i read chunks of the file and uploads it to my web service (it MUST upload to this webservice, since it is on another server). Some of my clients are having problems using the Silverlight (most due to security policies). So i want to convert it to plain HTTP upload with progress. Is this possible to do using ASP.NET MVC? How do i chunk the file without the UI stalling and is non-responsive? Is there any "good" approach to this. How do e.g. google accomplish it in their gmail. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never found an ansver, still using Silverlight

Answer (score 1):

You need to stream the large file uploads. Please refer to following [Streaming large file uploads to ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046230/streaming-large-file-uploads-to-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thats not it, they upload from a windows application to a web page/service, i want to post the file from another web page. I want to do everything in HTML.