# Create FileStream from local file without uploading it before in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

I want to upload big files per ftp and as I am not able to get the full path for security reasons, I search for a method to **create a FileStream** for example from a Filechooser **WITHOUT already uploading the file**. 
As far as I understood, when I use PostedFile, it will be already uploaded. As the files are vergy big, this is not the solution I search for.
Is there any solution?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046230/streaming-large-file-uploads-to-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @Rfvgyhn I don't think it's a duplicate, but it's definitely related and can help solve his problem I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You can't access to local file from JavaScript, you can't run server side C# code against client side file system.

You need some sort of client side application to do that. You can use Silverlight/Flash to get a stream as result of file picker dialog and upload files that way. Possible Flash approach covered in [ActionScript2: Adding file upload functionality](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001054.html).

Comment: Thanks, that helps me, as it is a clear answer :) I will search for a Silverlight solution - I already tried actually but got errors, that I am not allowed to access local machine. Probably I just got the wrong approach.

Comment: Here is the solution in silverlight, but you have to create a full trusted application: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/local-file-access-in-silverlight-4/